# Parse JSON String to Date

Tags: json, date, parsing, objectmapper

I want to parse a JSON String to a date but parsing does not work:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not
>   deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "2006-02-20
>   05:32:40.0": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"  at [Source:
>   {
>                "ORD_START_TIME": "2006-02-20 05:32:40.0",
>                "ENDE_TIME": "2006-02-20 06:15:33.0",
>                }; line: 3, column: 32] (through reference chain: ["ORD_START_TIME"])

I use @JsonFormat for the mapping in the entity class:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
@JsonProperty("ORD_START_TIME")
private Date ordStartTime;
```

Any ideas?

I use Java Spring

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the format pattern to match the data?

Comment: Yes, I have tried already several options.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. It was necessary to set following property for the Object Mapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
```